# Want to understand this permission of /usr/bin/sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo

I was getting below error while running command **sudo -s** after changing the permission to 777 of /usr/bin/sudo

> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Ii solved this by below process:

> Select your OS version in (recovery mode), and press Enter Key.

Ex : Ubuntu 14.04 (recovery mode)

It will bring you up another screen. Now select “Drop to root shell prompt” and press Enter.

It will load a command line at the bottom of the screen.

Now run each of the following commands.

mount -o remount,rw /

mount –all

chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

restart

**Now**, I just want to understand why it was not working with 777 permission on /usr/bin/sudo

Please explain, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` has the "setuid" bit (the `4` in `chmod 4755`). It means that when you execute `sudo`, you automatically get the privileges of `sudo`'s owner, which is root. So any execution of `sudo` has root privileges, it's just that the first thing the "official" version does is asking for a password to determine it it can continue.

If `sudo` is word-writable, then anyone can patch it to not check passwords or do other things, and so gain access to root privileges. So `sudo` must be kept R/O for everyone otherwise it should be considered as compromised.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a simple security feature where if the /usr/bin/sudo has different permissions to 755 it will become inaccessible. I couldn't find an article to confirm this so I'd say this is my guess. However you can find a lot of people asking the same thing an always everyone telling them to revert to 755 permissions